# edit customer account info links

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, customer-account

In `/customer/account` there are several links

- account dashboard
- account information
- addressbook
- etc

I do not have any need (as far as i can tell) for:

- recurring profiles
- my applications
- my downloadable products (or I must be needing this when using gift card module, I don't know yet)

Where can I turn these off? It should be update proof ;-)

Answer (score 10):

An alternative approach to Amit's is in your theme's `local.xml` to replace the parent block customer_account_navigation completely and then only add the links you want to show. Use the below and then delete the lines you don't want. Please note that if in the future any other links need to be added you would need to copy them into your `local.xml` to show up. As an extra benefit you can easily reorder the items.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <customer_account>
        <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>                    
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="downloadable"><name>downloadable_products</name><path>downloadable/customer/products</path><label>My Downloadable Products</label></action>                    
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="newsletter"><name>newsletter</name><path>newsletter/manage/</path><label>Newsletter Subscriptions</label></action>                    
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="review"><name>reviews</name><path>review/customer</path><label>My Product Reviews</label></action>                    
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>orders</name><path>sales/order/history/</path><label>My Orders</label></action>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="tag"><name>tags</name><path>tag/customer/</path><label>My Tags</label></action>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="wishlist" ifconfig="wishlist/general/active"><name>wishlist</name><path>wishlist/</path><label>My Wishlist</label></action>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="oauth">
                    <name>OAuth Customer Tokens</name>
                    <path>oauth/customer_token</path>
                    <label>My Applications</label>
                </action>                    
        </block>
    </customer_account>
</layout>
```

Comment: Simple to use and does not required any installation. Nice work. Upvoted

Answer (score 4):

Magento is  add link on `customer account left` hand side using `addLink` function on `Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation` here

```
public function addLink($name, $path, $label, $urlParams=array())
{
    $this->_links[$name] = new Varien_Object(array(
        'name' => $name,
        'path' => $path,
        'label' => $label,
        'url' => $this->getUrl($path, $urlParams),
    ));
    return $this;
}
```

Magento add those  link by this xml code

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name>

<path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
```

### Most easy Process

there `lot of layout xml` file like `tag.xml,outh.xml,customer.xml,checkout.xml`

are  which is included  there  `link on left navigation  using addLink function`
.If  your layout  folder`app/design/frontend/your package/your template/layout/`  did not have those files  but it `links are  available` at your `account left navigation` then according  to magento fallback  logic need to copy those from `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/` to `app/design/frontend/your package/your template/layout/`.

Then comment  this code those file.

to go  your `layout xmls file` find  `<action method="addLink"` code and remove those code

### Right Process Using local.xml

Create  an method on `Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation` on remove the link using below code

```
public function removeLink($removename)
{
    unset($this->_links[$removename]);
    return $this;
}
```

You need to create an extension for this

**Step1:** Rewrite class   `Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation`  using class `Amit_RemoveNavigation_Block_Customer_Account_Navigation`

Create a file Navigation.php at app\code\local\Amit\RemoveNavigation\Block\Customer\Account

```
<?php
class Amit_RemoveNavigation_Block_Customer_Account_Navigation extends Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation
{
    public function removeLink($removename)
    {
        unset($this->_links[$removename]);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Step2:** create `config.xml` at `app\code\local\Amit\RemoveNavigation\etc` and

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Amit_RemoveNavigation>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Amit_RemoveNavigation>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <removenavigation>
        <class>Amit_RemoveNavigation_Helper</class>
      </removenavigation>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <removenavigation>
        <class>Amit_RemoveNavigation_Block</class>
      </removenavigation>
            <customer>
                <rewrite>
                    <account_navigation>Amit_RemoveNavigation_Block_Customer_Account_Navigation</account_navigation>
                </rewrite>
            </customer>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

**Step3:** create helper class for this module  `Data.php` at a`pp\code\local\Amit\RemoveNavigation\Helper`

```
<?php
class Amit_RemoveNavigation_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

Step4: create modules control file `Amit_RemoveNavigation.xml` at `app/etc/modules/`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Amit_RemoveNavigation>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Amit_RemoveNavigation>
  </modules>
</config>
```

You will  see at outh.xml this code

```
  <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="oauth">
            <name>OAuth Customer Tokens</name>
            <path>oauth/customer_token</path>
            <label>My Applications</label>
        </action>
    </reference>
```

which is add on  my applications link on left navigation

so create  `local.xml` at `app/design/frontend/your package/your template/layout/`

add this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
       <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="removeLink" translate="label" module="oauth">
                <name>OAuth Customer Tokens</name> <!-- remove by name -->
            </action>
        </reference>
</layout>
```

You will see  the below code at `downloadable.xml`

```
<customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="downloadable"><name>downloadable_products</name><path>downloadable/customer/products</path><label>My Downloadable Products</label></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
```

As i told  i have add  remove the link by tag `<name>downloadable_products</name>`so add local.xml code i look like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
       <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="removeLink" translate="label" module="oauth">
                <name>OAuth Customer Tokens</name> <!-- remove by name -->
            </action>
       <action method="removeLink" translate="label" module="oauth">
                <name>downloadable_products</name> <!-- remove by name -->
            </action>

    </reference>
</layout>
```

In magento add this by

this  tag according to your logic

```
<name>recurring_profiles</name>   
<name>billing_agreements</name>
<name>reviews</name>
<name>downloadable_products</name>
<name>OAuth Customer Tokens</name>

<name>account</name>
<name>account_edit</name>
<name>address_book</name>
<name>orders</name>
<name>tags</name>
<name>wishlist</name>
<name>newsletter</name>
```

Comment: Wow thats a big difference with the first answer... what makes this better (or worse?)

Comment: calro,this function removeLinkByName  is not find in msgento 1.9

Comment: ah ok, clear... i'm going to try your method... is it safe to do?

Comment: please see update

Answer (score 4):

Just do this in your local.xml

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation" >
            <!-- remove the link using your custom method -->
            <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>recurring_profiles</name>   </action>
            <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>billing_agreements</name></action>
            <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>reviews</name></action>
            <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>downloadable_products</name></action>
            <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>OAuth Customer Tokens</name></action>

            <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>account</name></action>
            <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>account_edit</name></action>
            <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>address_book</name></action>
            <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>orders</name></action>
            <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>tags</name></action>
            <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>wishlist</name></action>
            <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>newsletter</name></action>

    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

Delete the links you want to keep. :-)

Comment: This did not work for me. Resulted an error.

Answer (score 0):

In CE 1.9.3 you can do the following:

1st remove the account navigation block entirely:

```
<!--Unset the whole block then add back later-->
<action method="unsetChild">
    <name>customer_account_navigation</name>
</action>
<block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer">
        <name>account</name>
        <path>customer/account/</path>
        <label>Account Dashboard</label>
    </action>
    <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer">
        <name>account_edit</name>
        <path>customer/account/edit/</path>
        <label>Account Information</label>
    </action>
    <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer">
        <name>address_book</name>
        <path>customer/address/</path>
        <label>Address Book</label>
    </action>
    <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales">
        <name>orders</name>
        <path>sales/order/history/</path>
        <label>My Orders</label>
    </action>
    <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="wishlist" ifconfig="wishlist/general/active">
        <name>wishlist</name>
        <path>wishlist/</path>
        <label>My Favorite</label>
    </action>
    <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="newsletter">
        <name>newsletter</name>
        <path>newsletter/manage/</path>
        <label>Newsletter Subscriptions</label>
    </action>
</block>
```

The you re-add the customer account navigation block & then add the required links.